# How to bind realm object to UISwitch using RxSwift and RxRealm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm newbie studying RxSwift and RxRealm.

Let me show you my ViewController first.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP0Ym.png)

This app is quite simple, add user's name, age, etc, and bool value into
Realm object and shows in table view

here is my question.

I want to update bool value to toggle UISwitch in tableview cell.

but I couldn't find any way to do it.

this is my code

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift
import RxRealm

class PersonInfo: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var age = 0
    @objc dynamic var etc = ""
    @objc dynamic var isOn = false
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var bgButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageTextfield: UITextField!{ didSet{ ageTextfield.keyboardType = .numberPad } }
    @IBOutlet weak var etcTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addItemButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var turnSwitch: UISwitch!{
        didSet {
            turnSwitch.isOn = false
        }
    }

    let bag = DisposeBag()
    var persons: Results<PersonInfo>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let realm = try! Realm()
        persons = realm.objects(PersonInfo.self)


        let nameTextObservable = nameTextfield.rx.text.orEmpty.asObservable()
            .map{ text -> Bool in
                text.count >= 1
        }

        let ageTextObservable = ageTextfield.rx.text.orEmpty.asObservable()
            .map{ text -> Bool in
                text.count >= 1
        }

        // enable or disable Add button
        Observable.combineLatest(nameTextObservable, ageTextObservable){ $0 && $1 }
        .bind(to: addItemButton.rx.isEnabled).disposed(by: bag)

        // show datas in tableview
        Observable.collection(from: persons)
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "cell", cellType: CustomCell.self)){
            row, element, cell in

            cell.nameLabel.text = element.name
            cell.ageLabel.text = String(element.age)
            cell.switch.isOn = element.isOn

        }
        .disposed(by: bag)

        // add data in realm
        addItemButton.rx.tap
        .map{ _ -> PersonInfo in
            let newPerson = PersonInfo()
            newPerson.name = self.nameTextfield.text!
            newPerson.age = Int(self.ageTextfield.text!)!
            newPerson.etc = self.etcTextfield.text ?? "empty"
            newPerson.isOn = self.turnSwitch.isOn

            return newPerson
            }
            .bind(to: Realm.rx.add())
            .disposed(by: bag)


        // dismiss keyboard
        bgButton.rx.tap
            .subscribe(onNext:{
                self.nameTextfield.resignFirstResponder()
                self.ageTextfield.resignFirstResponder()
                self.etcTextfield.resignFirstResponder()
            })
            .disposed(by: bag)
    }
}
```

And This is CustomCell

```
import UIKit
import RxCocoa
import RxRealm
import RxSwift
import RealmSwift

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    let bag = DisposeBag()

    var persons: Results<PersonInfo>!

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var switch: UISwitch!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let realm = try! Realm()
        persons = realm.objects(PersonInfo.self)

        // I thought I need to do something here
        // something like this below
        alarmSwitch.rx.value
        .subscribe{
            // get index of selected cell
            // update data
        }
        .disposed(by: bag)

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }
}
```

Can you give me any clue to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you use an @IBAction for the button toggle and through that update your object?

Comment: oh. that could be an way of solving this problem!. Thanks a lot. I'll try to solve it that way.